# Laravel api route 404

Tags: laravel

I am running `LNMP`, the project is using React and Laravel.

In React frontend, when `Sign In` button is click and login form is submitted, it calls to

```
Http.Post('/api/v1/auth/login', credential)
```

In `api.php` I have something like this:

```
Route::group([  
    'prefix' => 'v1/auth'  
], function ($router) {  
    Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');  
    ...
});
```

But nginx `access.log` records:

> 127.0.0.1 - - [29/Aug/2020:16:29:59 +0800] "POST /api/v1/auth/login HTTP/1.1" 404 197 "http://127.0.0.1/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36"

Also, this action with `artisan serve` works just fine. So I assume this is something related with my config, but I really don't know where to look at.

Comment: Do you have your nginx setup to redirect all calls to Laravel's index.php? The routes, for example `/api/v1/auth/login` only works when you redirect that to `/index.php/api/v1/auth/login`

Comment: Hi Robin, thanks for your insight. I just learned that `artisan serve` actually set the site's entry to server.php, which will do some redirection. so the redirect might be the case. But I tried add `rewrite (.*)/api/(.*) $1/index.php/api/$2;` in my nginx config, which didn't work. It is now `POST /index.php/api/v1/auth/login 404`. Do you have any thought?

Comment: I think you're best off checking the official Laravel documentation for nginx config snippets, or to look for some tutorial that provides it. This for example? https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/deployment#nginx

Comment: to secure your route looks ok run 'php artisan route:list' and see if it looks correct.